# Caused by:java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: java, lwjgl

Today I was working on my program and I got this error.

```
Caused by:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.cubeville.blocks.CrossedBlockBrush cannot be  cast to org.cubeville.blocks.DefaultBlockBrush
```

My program is in Java of course. It uses lwjgl and slick. I was wondering what might cause this and if there is a for sure fix.

Thank You

Comment: We're going to need to see the part of your code that threw this exception.

Comment: Your trying to cast a CrossedBlockBrush to a type DefaultBlockBrush which it cannot do. I have no idea what that package is you are using so its a little hard to help. Look at the stack trace and follow it to find out what is throwing the Cast Exception and post the code around that then it might be easier to help.

Comment: ' public DefaultBlockBrush getDefaultBlockBrush()
 {
  return (DefaultBlockBrush) brush;
 }
 
 public CrossedBlockBrush getCrossedBlockBrush()
 {
  return (CrossedBlockBrush) brush;
 }'

Then the CrossedBlockBrush class is at: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/855851/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check that `DefaultBlockBrush` is indeed a supertype of `CrossedBlockBrush`. If it's not, then the cast is simply illegal. Check whether you're using the same version of your library for both compiling and running; perhaps this relationship holds for one but not the other.

If `DefaultBlockBrush` is indeed a supertype of `CrossedBlockBrush`, then you the only way you could get this kind of message would be if `CrossedBlockBrush` and `DefaultBlockBrush` were loaded by two different class loaders. This kind of thing can happen in a badly configured web application, or an application based on some other component-based system with multiple `ClassLoader`s like OSGi.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting something like

```
DefaultBlockBrush blockBrush = (DefaultBlockBrush) brush;
```

but brush, on the right hand side is of type CrossedBlockBrush. You could do that if CrossedBlockBrush was a subclass of DefaultBlockBrush, but apparently it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that:-

```
org.cubeville.blocks.CrossedBlockBrush
```

cannot be cast to a:-

```
org.cubeville.blocks.DefaultBlockBrush
```

But that is just saying what the exception said.

Somewhere in your code you have:-

```
instance = (DefaultBlockBrush) originalInstance
```

and because `CrossedBlockBrush` doesn't implement or extend a `DefaultBlockBrush` you are getting a cast exception.